# !Ref function in aws-cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How to call !Ref function in aws-cdk stack? I have a UserPool resource and UserPoolClientResource with userPoolId property:

```
const userPool = new cognito.cloudformation.UserPoolResource(this, userPoolResourceName, {
  userPoolName,
  usernameAttributes: ['email'],
  autoVerifiedAttributes: ['email'],
  policies: {
    passwordPolicy: {
      minimumLength: 8,
      requireLowercase: false,
      requireNumbers: false,
      requireSymbols: false,
      requireUppercase: false
    }
  }
});

new cognito.cloudformation.UserPoolClientResource(this, userPoolClientResourceName, {
  userPoolId: `!Ref ${userPool.id}`, // failed
  clientName: userPoolClientName
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDK renames the `Ref` to make them look like any other properties, and they have a name that is automatically generated from the resource name and the `Ref` type (typically either `Name`, `Id` or `Arn`).

In the particular case you're facing here, you need to use the [`UserPoolResource.userPoolId`](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-cognito.html?highlight=userpool#@aws-cdk/aws-cognito.cloudformation.UserPoolResource.userPoolId) property (`userPool` is the resource type name, and `Id` is the `Ref` type).